# Как различать разряды прилагательных?

Tags: прилагательные

Всем привет!

Я вдруг понял, что путаю разряды прилагательных.
Видимо, нужно правильно вопросы задавать?

Качественные: какой (ая, ие)?

Относительные: тут не знаю.

Притяжательные: чей?

Не подскажете, в вопросах ли дело?

Comment: Вопрос чисто школьный, ответ есть в любом учебнике, разбирайтесь сами - несложно. Или задайте вопрос относительно конкретного прилагательного. Не может же быть, что непонятно вообще ничего?!

Примеры качественных: красивый рисунок, тяжелый чемодан, крупная рыба. Примеры относительных: деревянный дом, железный лом, детская книга.

Answer (score 4):

Сложность тут единственная: качественные и относительные прилагательные иногда могут меняться местами, так что правильно или неправильно заданный к ним вопрос не поможет (с притяжательными проще).

[Таблица разрядов прилагательных с примерами позволит быстро определить разряд рассматриваемого слова.](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/razryady-prilagatelnyh)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или чуть по-другому:

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

И ещё с примерами:

**[РАЗРЯДЫ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫХ](http://www.fio.ru/tables/adjective/razryady-prilagatelnykh-/)**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ВАЖНО!**

**Различия качественных и относительных прилагательных:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**[Переход прилагательных из одного разряда в другой](http://www.fio.ru/tables/adjective/razryady-prilagatelnykh-/)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я, выходит, путался в основном в качественных и относительных прилагательных. Теперь у меня есть надежные признаки каждого . Спасибо за развернутый ответ: блестяще  - то что искал.